# How to check for new files that are copied to a specific folder?

Tags: python, text-files, daemon

There is a folder with name `TEXT_FILES`.
Users on the network will copy text files into that folder.
And my python code(application) will periodically look into that folder.
If text there are files, it will process them.

Could you help me with code?
Could you give some hints, please?

Comment: Just go on an adventure and try some things yourself, should you get stuck you can always come back with a specific problem & question. As it stands your question is a little too broad.

Comment: Also, as there are unlimited possibilities to go about this, start with something and then ask for help with your specific solution.

Comment: You should specify the OS you are interested in. There are basically two ways to do it: Polling the directory periodically with something like `os.listdir` or `glob.glob` or have the OS notify you when the directory changes. The first is portable, the other is OS dependent.

Comment: Hi namco, if you find my answer helpful, would you consider accepting it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
from os.path import splitext
from threading import Timer

# depends on what kind of text files you'll get
text = (".txt", '.py', '.md', ...)  

def process_files():
    for f in glob.glob('TEXT_FILES/*'):
        if f.splitext()[1] in text:
        # process file

# run process_files every 10s
Timer(10, process_files).start()
```

Comment: @Trimax Sorry I wrote a lot of Js these days :)

Answer (score -1):

To find files within a folder you can try the `glob` module:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html

Comment: 'link-only' answers are not really appreciated on SO, it's always best to include a code example or something

Comment: @TimCastelijns You should take that guideline with a pinch of salt. Regarding python modules, what's a more reliable link than a link to the documentation itself? Also, franzwr provided enough context so that, even if the link is ever broken (unlikely), you can search for it on google. I think this is a perfectly acceptable answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @DerGolem Read my comment above.

Answer (score -2):

Why don't you take a look @ Pyinotify 
http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/

```
$ sudo pip install pyinotify  
$ python -m pyinotify -v /your-dir-to-watch
```

This will satisfy your need I guess!

Comment: 'link-only' answers are not really appreciated on SO, it's always best to include a code example or something